# SQL Query works fine in SMS but not when executing from ORM, DateTime Conversion error

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, fluentdata

I have the following query in C# using `FluentData` ORM.

```
List<dynamic> results = 
   Context().Sql(@"SELECT DISTINCT
                      a.EnteredDate,
                      bb.PK_EmployeeName,
                      bb.EmployeeId,
                      bb.EmployeeName,
                      dd.PK_EquipmentName,
                      dd.EquipmentId,
                      dd.EquipmentName
                   FROM 
                      dbo.PIT_Inspection a
                   INNER JOIN 
                      dbo.PIT_EmployeeName bb ON a.FK_EmployeeName = bb.PK_EmployeeName
                   INNER JOIN 
                      dbo.PIT_EquipmentName dd ON a.FK_EquipmentName = dd.PK_EquipmentName
                   WHERE 
                      CAST(a.EnteredDate AS DATE) BETWEEN '@0' AND @1'", 
                  fromDate, toDate ).QueryMany<dynamic>();
```

The parameters `fromDate` and `toDate` are `strings` and come populated with the following:

- `fromDate` = "20150224"
- `toDate` = "20150227"

The area that seems to give me problem is:

```
WHERE CAST(a.EnteredDate AS DATE) BETWEEN '@0' AND '@1'", 
   fromDate , toDate
```

I'm receiving an error

> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string

The above line, `a.EnteredDate` is of type `DateTime`. The query I'm executing, if copied over to SQL Server Management Studio, it runs fine. I double checked that my parameter is indeed bringing in correct data, as string.

Any idea on what causes this error?

Comment: Get rid of the '' around @0 and @1.  The orm will use a SqlParameter object to represent @0 and @1 and will automatically do that for you.  That applies to all parameters like that, regardless of type.

Comment: Secondly you have a typo in your query "'@0' AND @1'", you have a closing apostrophe after @1 but no opening apostrophe before @1.  But you don't need the apostrophes at all.

Comment: @Ryios Thank you, your first comment helped me fix the problem. Didn't know that it will automatically handle that for me. Note on your second comment - Look at my first code example, i do have an opening double quote. Either way, you should put this as answer for me to accept. It may help others.

Comment: My second comment was refering to this line     BETWEEN '@0' AND @1' where the apostrophe (not double quote) is missing from the start of @ 1'  It's hard to see the apostrophes in my comment, they are crammed up next to the double quotes.

Comment: Oh I see what you were referring to, it was correct on my code before I made the changes you recommended. I must've erased it by mistake when copying it over here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most ORM's convert @ parameters into SqlParameter objects, which handle typing for you so you don't need to enclose your query variables in apostrophes to denote a string.

So change

```
'@0' AND @1'
```

to

```
@0 AND @1
```

This likely applies to FluentData, and definitely applies to PetaPoco, and EntityFramework.